# How to get all items from three dynamoDB tables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Good day everyone. I know it might not be efficient way to "query" the database but how I can do  it?
As I understand we can get this using DTO pattern, its a none entity class. I use Spring Boot for this task.
Also, I would like to know how to sort them if all three tables have one common column.
I intentionally dont use single table for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get all items from any table is by using a Scan. You have to read from all three tables separately.

As for the sorting, Scan will not return all items sorted, for each item-collection in the table it will be returned sorted based on the tables sort key, but there is not sort order across different partition keys.

Order could be returned like this:

| PK | SK |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| X | 1 |
| X | 2 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 7 |
| A | 9 |